# Relaunch LocationManager after exiting a region

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have an app which uses the users location in the background and foreground. In the background when the user stops the vehicle the app automatically goes to sleep and calls `stopUpdatingLocation`. Everything works as expected.

Now I want to make sure the app relaunches it self when the user starts driving again. To achieve this I add a region with 200m radius with the last location just before I call `stopUpdatingLocation`. With the method `didExitRegion` I just call `startUpdatingLocation` again.

This gives me mixed results, it seems that sometimes the simulator works as expected but when driving around I cannot get this to work. The `exitRegion` works because I can receive a `localNotification`.

My question:
Is above possible, so is it possible to wake the app and start updating the users location in the background ?

Are there any code examples available achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW60) and  [stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)

From Apple;

> The significant location change service delivers events normally while an app is running in the foreground or background. For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.